# What's the name of a problem, when you need to determine the moment to stop searching for a better solution?

Tags: probability

I heard this problem in a form like this (it's not exact wording):

> There are N bachelors. Girl evaluates each of them one after another
>   to find the best one. She can either chose a current bachelor as a
>   final solution, or she can proceed with the next one. At which moment
>   she should stop?

What's the name of this problem? (i.e. how to google it?)
I'm also curious, if there is any approach to solve this problem when number of bachelors is infinite?

Comment: "When the number of bachelors is infinite" needs to be made more specific. In the original problem, there is an ordering of best to worst (assuming you could actually rank all the bachelors). So when you say infinite, are you putting an upper bound on "best?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is often called [the secretary problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem). See also [Math story: Ten marriage candidates and 'greatest of all time'](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94460/math-story-ten-marriage-candidates-and-greatest-of-all-time/94466#94466)

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is called an
[optimal stopping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_stopping) problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Clio Cresswell](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/ut/people?who=c_cresswell) calls this the *12 bonk rule* and has managed to get it mentioned in the media (refs: [Sydney Morning Herald](http://www.smh.com.au/lifestyle/life/blogs/ask-sam/the-12-bonk-theory-the-sex-you-should-have-before-settling-down-20101115-17tot.html); [Catalyst](http://www.abc.net.au/catalyst/stories/s2062649.htm)), using the eyecatching title as a means to (a) make mathematics seem more "cool", and (b) attract more females to mathematics.

See also her book "Mathematics and Sex" (refs: [Google Books](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=NlaW8VNV-TsC); [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1741141591)).